# No such file or directory when piping. Each command works separately, but not when piping

Tags: linux, bash, sed, sh

I have 2 folders: `folder_a` & `folder_b`. In each of these folders there are a bunch of files. I am trying to use `sed` to move all of these files out of these folders and into my current working directory I am currently in.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
mytest:
    a:
        1.txt
        2.txt
        3.txt
    b:
        4.txt
        5.txt
```

The command I am trying to use is:

```
find . -type d ! -iname '*.*'  # find all folders other than root
    | sed -r 's/.*/&\/*/'      # add '/*' to each of the arguments
    | sed -r 'p;s/.*/./'       # output: a/* . b/* .
    | xargs -n 2 mv            # should be creating two commands: 'mv a/* .' and 'mv b/* .'
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

```
mv: cannot stat './aaa/*': No such file or directory
```

I also get the same error when I try this other strategy (using ls instead of mv):

```
for dir in */; do
  ls $dir;
done;
```

Even if I use sed to replace the spaces in each directory name with '\ ', or surround the directory names with quotes I get the same error.

I'm not sure if these 2 examples are related in my misunderstanding of bash but they both seem to demonstrate my ignorance of how bash translates the output from one command into the input of another command.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `xargs` isn't expanding your globs. There's no shell involved there. You need a shell for globs to expand. Is there a reason you aren't just using `mv */* .`?

Comment: could something much simpler be used such as `find . -type d ! -iname '*.*' | while read d; do mv $d/* .; done`

Comment: just a hint. you don't call what you referred to `root`. it's current working directory(cwd) or present working directory(pwd).

Comment: Why not use `mv */* .`?

Comment: I am not using mv \*/\* . just in case there are other folders in my current working directory that I do not want to touch. I am doing this partially as a learning exercise so I am trying to solve the problem in different ways.

Comment: Thank you HuStmpHrrr. Edited.

Comment: @fusilli.jerry89: In light of your later comments I've rewritten my answer; the `find` solution is now much more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Update: Completely rewritten.</sup>

As @EtanReisner and @melpomene have noted, **`mv */* .` or, more specifically, `mv a/* b/* .` is the most straightforward solution**, but you state that this is in part a learning exercise, so the remainder of the answer shows an efficient `find`-based solution and explains the problem with the original command.

#### An efficient `find`-based solution

Generally, if feasible, it's best and most efficient to let `find` itself do the work, without involving additional tools; `find`'s `-exec` action is like a built-in `xargs`, with `{}` representing the path at hand (with terminator `\;`) / *all* paths (with `+`):

```
find . -type f -exec echo mv -t . {} +
```

<sup>To be safe, his will just *print* the `mv` *commands* that *would* be executed; remove the `echo` to actually execute them.</sup>

This will execute a *single*<sup>[1]</sup> `mv` command to which *all* matching files are passed, and `-t .` moves them all to the current dir.

<sup>[1] If the resulting command line is too long (which is unlikely), it is split up into multiple commands, just as with `xargs`.</sup>

Operating on *files* (`-type f`) bypasses the need for globbing, as `find` will then enumerate all files for you (it also bypasses the need to exclude `.` explicitly).

Note that this solution works on entire *subtrees*, not just (immediate) subdirectories.
<sup>It's tempting to consider turning on Bash 4's `globstar` option and using `mv */** .`, but that won't work, because it will attempt to move *directories* as well, not just the files in them.</sup>

A **caveat re `-exec` with `+`**: it only works if `{}` - the placeholder for all paths - is the token *immediately before* the `+`.

<sup>Since you're on Linux, we can satisfy this condition by specifying the target folder for `mv` with *option* `-t` *before* the `{}`; on BSD-based systems such as OSX, you could *not* do that, because `mv` doesn't support `-t` there, so you'd have to use terminator `\;`, which means that `mv` is called *once for every path*, which is obviously much slower.</sup>

---

#### Why your command didn't work:

As @EtanReisner points out in a comment, **`xargs` invokes the command specified without (implicitly) involving a shell, so globbing won't work**; you can verify this with the following command:

```
echo '*' | xargs echo  # -> '*' - NO globbing
```

If we leave the globbing issue aside, additional work would have been necessary to make your `xargs` command work correctly with folder names with embedded spaces (or other shell metacharacters):

```
 find . -mindepth 1 -type d | 
    sed -r "s/.*/'&'\/* ./" | # -> '<input-path>'/* . (including single-quotes)
         xargs -n 2 echo mv # NOTE: still won't work due to lack of globbing
```

Note how the (combined) `sed` command now produces a *single* output line `'<input-path>'/* .`, with the input path enclosed in *embedded* single-quotes, which is required for `xargs` to recognize `<input-path>` as a single argument, even if it contains embedded spaces.
(If your filenames contain single-quotes, you'd have to do more work; also note that since now all arguments for a given dir. are on a *single* line, you could use `xargs -L 1 ...`.)

Also note how `-mindepth 1` (only process paths at the subdirectory level or below) is used to skip processing of `.` itself.

The only way to **make globbing happen** is to **get the shell involved**:

```
 find . -mindepth 1 -type d | 
    sed -r "s/.*/'&'\/* ./" | # -> '<input-path>'/* . (including single-quotes)
         xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo mv {}' # works, but is inefficient
```

Note the use of `xargs`' `-I` option to treat each input line as its own argument (`{}` is a self-chosen placeholder for the input).

`sh -c` invokes the (default) shell to execute the resulting command, at which globbing does happen.

However, overall, this is quite inefficient:

- A pipeline with 3 segments is used.
- A shell instance is invoked for *every* input path, which in turn calls the `mv` utility.

Compare this to the efficient `find`-only solution above, which (typically) creates only *2* processes *in total*.